# What's wrong with this php syntax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am getting error in my browsers console while executing this code :-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
           if(<?php (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/web/login/index/1') === 0)?>) {
              var loggedOut= <?=$fb_logout;?>;
            }
           else{
             var loggedOut = null;  
            }

        some more java script
        .
        .
        .


        .  
      </script>
```

What I am trying to do is to initialise the loggedOut with a value 1 which is stored in fb_logout if the request comes from a page having /web/login/index/1 part of URl. I am getting error in the browsers console saying    "Syntax error"   pointing just after "if()" closing parantheses saying "jquery.min.js (line 3, col 15)"  . I am using jQuery library.

Thanks

Comment: why two closing script tags?

Comment: btw: your `script` open tag is wrong

Comment: Just a tip: what does your browser see? Maybe `if() { ...`? Also, you're opening with a closing `</script>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return/display the result of your statement:

```
<?=((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/web/login/index/1') === 0) ? 'true': 'false')?>
```

Comment: Do you really think you are saving doing `<?=` instead `<?php echo`?

Comment: I'm just used to `<?=`, what's the problem?

Comment: Note that `echo false;` does not produce any output, so the generated JavaScript code would be `if() { ...` which will be a syntax error.

Comment: Not all PHP environments support `<?=`, iirc

Comment: Thanks Felix, I've used a casting operator just in case

Comment: Ok I've made it more explicit

Comment: Note that since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available; as much as I personally dislike the syntax, fighting the adoption of it is a lost cause now.

Comment: Thanks MMM, thanks for your answer.Thanks to every one for showing interest in this question, and all along I was hesitant to ask this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid outputting whole if statement/branch instead of outputting useless if (false)? Would save some bandwidth + CPU on client side.

Answer (score 3):

Main answer: You're not outputing the result of your comparison.

Suggestion: How about using the ternary operator?

```
 var loggedOut = <?php echo (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/web/login/index/1') === 0) ? $fb_logout :  'null' ?>
```

Comment: Thanks you Suggestion is really elegant. I will be using it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Now, try to check this:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/web/login/index/1') === 0) {
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

As the very first PHP code on your code above.

Comment: I think I needed to echo the result of this comparison.

Comment: Do you mean, the `<?=$fb_logout;?>` will stored to the var `loggedOut` when the requested URI returns `/web/login/index/1`? Try to check my updates above..

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted. And thanks a bunch. It was real pleasure to have recieved help from you.

Comment: @user1590011 If that's exactly what you've wanted, then why you did not choose it as the right answer?

Comment: Respected Sir the chosen answer came to me earlier than your correct answer, moreover it was the chosen answer which first made me to realize my folly.And I wanted to set the value of $logout to 1 based on the condition check, which nowhere seems to be happening in your code. But your idea is correct and I am thankful indeed, please feel the warmth of it. Also in the interest of full disclosure I would like to mention that I did upvoted your esteemed answer. Thanks alot.